# The value for a v-bind expression cannot be empty. Found in "v-bind:items"

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I am new to Vue. I am using a vue component as follows & I am passing some objects through the components if available.

```html
<form :languages='{{ json_encode($languages) }}'
      :items='{{ !empty($items) ? $items : "" }}'>
</form>
```

I am using this vue component for both create new entry and edit existing entry scenarios. so, this **:items** (it is and list of objects) only have values if it is using edit function. but if it is create new function it don't have this :items. when I am using this vue component for the add new function it gives me the following error and not loading the vue component.

*Error message:*

> The value for a v-bind expression cannot be empty. Found in "v-bind:items".

I want to load this vue component for both scenarios I already mentioned(create new & edit functions), so is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. What is `items` supposed to be? In your case it evaluates to `:items=""`, which is a mistake.

Comment: @Estus Flask I have edited the question and it describes what is this :items.

Comment: Please, stick to technical point of view and check https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Is it an object? An array? A string? What exactly do you expect it to be when it's empty? null? Empty string? Empty object? The question is very specific to PHP which wasn't mentioned in the question, you would probably wouldn't have this problem if Vue code were written from scratch with JS alone. Try to write a correct expression in Vue and then provide a respective value from PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v-bind` doesn't allow empty binding-expression values, which would happen if `empty($items)` evaluates to `true`.

You could set it to an empty array for that case:

```html
<form :items='{{ !empty($items) ? $items : "[]" }}'>
```